# How implement pinch zoom without preserving aspect ratio in windows runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a scrollviewer around a canvas object

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and I'm adding (lots of) inherited custom controls into the Canvas in the code allowing me to basically create an interactive diagram:

```
var myControl = new MyControl();
myControl.Height = 10;
myControl.Width = 20;
Canvas.SetLeft(myControl,5);
Canvas.SetTop(myControl,20);
this.myCanvas.Children.Add(myControl);
```

The ScrollViewer allows me to pan and pinch zoom around this canvas of controls keeping the same aspect ratio quite nicely.

Is there any way to easily implement stretching using pinching i.e. zooming without maintaining aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (basically implementing Filip's answer):

```
<Image x:Name="_image" Stretch="None" ManipulationDelta="OnManipulationDelta">
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform />
  </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var ct = (CompositeTransform)_image.RenderTransform;
  // Scale horizontal.
  ct.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
  // Scale vertical.
  ct.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
}
```

You should only have one of the scaling statements above in your case.

Comment: You'll need a lower-level event than that, to give you the x- and y-spacing separately.  Maybe you can recover them from `expansion` and `rotation`.

Comment: Care to explain a bit more? You can post your answer as well.

Comment: Nice!  That will definitely get me going in the right direction!

Comment: As far as I know Filip was correct. However you sound optimistic in your last comment. Did you ever get independent x and y scaling working?

Answer (score 1):

ScrollViewer doesn't support that. You would need to roll out your own implementation using pointer or manipulation events and RenderTransform.

Comment: Meh!  That's what I thought the answer would be! :-(  Thank you for confirming my thoughts.